# Is SQL Server Compact Edition Serverless?

Tags: c#

Is SQL Server Compact Edition Serverless?

I mean, If I have a Northwind.sdf file in some pc without SQL server installed, can my application still use that?

Is it the same with SQLITE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

Both of these databases do not have servers and do not require any installation for end-user.

All you need to do is include the appropriate DLL file

Comment: really! thanks. Last question sir... does sqlite syntax fully supports MS Sql Syntax?

Comment: @yonan: Which parts? They're not totally identical.  See http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: ah ok.... I guess I have to choose SQL Server Compact Edition over SQLite, to save time converting MS SQL syntax to SQLite syntax.

Comment: @yonan: The syntax is similar, but not identical.  If you don't use any advanced features, your code should work fine with SQLite.  Note that SQL CE also doesn't support all of the SQL features that SQL Servr does.

Comment: ok... any disadvantages using SQL Server Compact Edition over SQLite? Which one do you recommend sir?

Comment: I have used both of them. I strongly recommend to use SQL CE. SqlLite is such a terrible system.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of SLaks + Yes, SQLite is an embedded database too.

SQLite features: SQLite doesn't support RIGHT or OUTER JOIN's, complete ALTER TABLE. See http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html.